# C - pointers and change address

Tags: c

I have this code that gives a pointer an address and print it, but why that does not work??

```
void main()
{
int *b = (int*) 32;
printf("%d\n",b[0]);
}
```

Comment: How does it not work?

Comment: I ran the code and it formatted my hard drive.

Comment: I am voting to close - I don't know what "does not work" mean.

Comment: You are assigning fake address read: [Invalid address causes Undefined behavior at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627394/why-do-we-store-string-in-a-character-pointer-e-g-in-fopen/17627415#17627415)

Answer (score 4):

`b[0]` dereferences an array which points to memory you haven't allocated.  The effects of doing this are undefined.  You might get a value returned or your program may crash if address `32` isn't readable from your process.

Comment: how to make it readable ?! i wanna read that

Comment: Its platform dependant. If the OS decides the address is not readable, there's nothing you can do. Why do you want to read this particular location in memory? Or do you want to print the address of b rather than what it points to

Answer (score 0):

```
int *b = (int*) 32;
```

above code assigns memory address 32 to this pointer, i don't think that is you want, you will get access denied error when you call printf, 
hope the following codes is useful toyou

```
int a = 32;
int *b = &a;
printf("%d\n",b[0]);
//output 32

printf( "%d\n", &b);
// output b pointer address.
```

Comment: Last one should be `%p`.

Comment: In addition to the last one being %p, I expect the intention is to print `b` rather than `&b`.

Comment: i wanna change the address and not print the address

Comment: if you wanna change the address, int *b = (int*) 32; is correctly， but (int*)32 is invalid pointer address, you should assign a valid pointer address to it.